# Why is the Bootstrap CSS not loading?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li>ONE</li>
                    <li>TWO</li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>LOG IN</li>
                    <li>HELP</li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--End nav container-->

        </div> <!--End nav-->

    </body>
</html>
```

As of right now the list is displaying at the default way HTML displays lists. the second link to a main.css is just a blank file I am not doing anything in it. These files are structured as such:

Documents/Web

There are both in my web folder.

Comment: You need to change `href="http://netd...`

Comment: http is not required in the href attribute. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036551/absolute-full-urls-without-http-in-html-href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're swapping btn with bnt, which won't render.

Try:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"> My Button </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/YuURs/